# Why it is possible to use unbalanced HTML formatting tags

Tags: html

When working with some nested HTML formatting tags, like `<b>` or `<i>` I've noticed that they work even if cross-nested with each other (i.e. one tag is not closed yet, but another already started, then first tag is closed, then second is closed).

For example,

`<b>My text <i>wit<s>h some mi</b>xed for</i>matt</s>ing`

**My text *wit<s>h some mi</s>***xed formatting

It's seems like it's not a valid HTML and browser (Chrome) shouldn't treat it like that, but it does.

Why is that? Is there some document which describes this behavior, like RFC document, or it is browser specific stuff?

Comment: because the browsers are smart :)

Comment: I suppose this is related to HTML's [adoption agency algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#adoptionAgency).

Comment: @OskarGrosser thanks, so it automatically create matching opener, not just automatically close unclosed formatting tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for historical reasons.

In the early days of the WWW, many people would roll their HTML code by hand, using only Notepad or other text-only editors, and many couldn't be bothered to stick to the specification.

Also, of the many HTML editors that were on the market back then, many would not only not strictly enforce the specification, but also actively generate invalid HTML code (one of the worst offenders being Microsoft Word - yes, people used Microsoft Word to create webpages!).

The creators of the browsers back then - Netscape and Microsoft - relented and implemented very lenient renderers that would successfully render even the most horrible HTML code.

The widespread disregard of the specification by website creators was also what lead to vastly different ways a page would be rendered on different browsers, often even on different versions of the same browser.

Comment: I see, thanks. Wonder if this behavior is reliable in different browsers.